# Unable to figure how to store "Save As" text in a string and use it

Tags: java, swing, awt, jfilechooser

[image]

I am new to UI design in Java. I am trying to create a GUI to download a file off the Internet and save it on your hard drive. I have got the code working except for one thing which I want to add. I have added a `JFileChooser` which lets the user select the destination folder. But I am unable to figure out how to change the `filename` to the one which user enters in the `Save As` bar on the `JFileChooser` menu.

**Browse Button**

```
browseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(null);
    chooser.setDialogTitle("Select folder to save");
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
    chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(true);

    //chooser.showDialog(downloadButton, "Save");
    if(chooser.showSaveDialog(downloadButton) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        System.out.println("The location to save is: " + chooser.getCurrentDirectory());
        DESTINATION_FOLDER = chooser.getCurrentDirectory().toString();
    }
}
```

});

**Download Button**

```
URLConnection connection = downloadUrl.openConnection();

input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
output = new FileOutputStream(DESTINATION_FOLDER + "/" + filename);
```

Here `filename` should be the one which user enters. Pointers on how to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need to get the FileName from the `Save As` Bar in the JFileChooser.
Just do like this:

```
    browseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(null);
        chooser.setDialogTitle("Select folder to save");
        //Don't use the 'FileSelectionMode();'. Let it be Default.
        chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(true);
   if(chooser.showSaveDialog(downloadButton) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
   {
    file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    //file should be declared as a File.
     System.out.println("The location to save is: " + chooser.getCurrentDirectory();));
     System.out.println("The FileName is: " + file.getName()); 
   }
}
```

DOWNLOAD BUTTON:

```
   URLConnection connection = downloadUrl.openConnection();
   input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
   output = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your code the best I could suggest is to create a Global String in the class you are working in.

```
public class gui extends JFrame{
    public String filePath="";
    public static void main(String args[]){
        //button code
        browseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener())
        saveAsButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener())
        URLConnection connection = downloadUrl.openConnection();



    }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("browseButton"){
        chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(null);
        chooser.setDialogTitle("Select folder to save");
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
        chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(true);

        //chooser.showDialog(downloadButton, "Save");
        if(chooser.showSaveDialog(downloadButton) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            System.out.println("The location to save is: "+chooser.getCurrentDirectory());
            filePath = chooser.getCurrentDirectory().toString();
        }
    else{
        //save as button selected
        input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        output = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But umm, I was actually asking how to use the `fileName` not `filePath` which the user specifies on the `Save As` text bar in the chooser menu. I have provided a pic for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line:

```
chooser.setDialogType(JFileChooser.SAVE_DIALOG);
```

Full code:

```
browseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(null);
    chooser.setDialogTitle("Select folder to save");
    chooser.setDialogType(JFileChooser.SAVE_DIALOG);
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
    chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(true);

    //chooser.showDialog(downloadButton, "Save");
    if(chooser.showSaveDialog(downloadButton) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        System.out.println("The location to save is: " + chooser.getCurrentDirectory());
        DESTINATION_FOLDER = chooser.getCurrentDirectory().toString();
    }
}
```